# Implementar constructor manualmente

Tags: c++, constructor

Tengo que modificar el siguiente programa para poder compilarlo con GCC 4.9.2. El problema es debido a que GCC no puede implementar algunos noexcept move constructors como "=default".

Tengo q implementar el constructor manualmente (a pie) y no sé cómo.

La linea 7 es la que esta causando problemas y es la q debe d modificarse:

```
'TabStats::TabStats(TabStats&& other) noexcept = default;'
```

Como condición es que no se debe de remover el noexcept specifier.

**Código fuente**:

```
#include "browser/resource_coordinator/tab_stats.h"
#include "build/build_config.h"

namespace resource_coordinator {
TabStats::TabStats() = default;
TabStats::TabStats(const TabStats& other) = default;
TabStats::TabStats(TabStats&& other) noexcept = default;
TabStats::~TabStats() {}
TabStats& TabStats::operator=(const TabStats& other) = default;
}  // namespace resource_coordinator
```

Tambien incluyo tab_stats.h aqui abajo:

```
#ifndef CHROME_BROWSER_RESOURCE_COORDINATOR_TAB_STATS_H_
#define CHROME_BROWSER_RESOURCE_COORDINATOR_TAB_STATS_H_
#include <stdint.h>
#include <vector>
#include "base/process/process.h"
#include "base/strings/string16.h"
#include "base/time/time.h"
#include "build/build_config.h"

namespace content {
class RenderProcessHost;
}  // namespace content

namespace resource_coordinator {

struct TabStats {
  TabStats();
  TabStats(const TabStats& other);
  TabStats(TabStats&& other) noexcept;
  ~TabStats();

  TabStats& operator=(const TabStats& other);

  bool is_app = false;            // Browser window is an app.
  bool is_internal_page = false;  // Internal page, such as NTP or Settings.
  // Playing audio, accessing cam/mic or mirroring display.
  bool is_media = false;
  bool is_pinned = false;
  bool is_in_visible_window = false;
  bool is_in_active_window = false;
  // Whether this is the active tab in a browser window.
  bool is_active = false;
  bool is_discarded = false;
  // User has entered text in a form.
  bool has_form_entry = false;
  int discard_count = 0;
  bool has_beforeunload_handler = false;
  base::TimeTicks last_active;
  base::TimeTicks last_hidden;
  content::RenderProcessHost* render_process_host = nullptr;
  base::ProcessHandle renderer_handle = 0;
  int child_process_host_id = 0;
  base::string16 title;
#if defined(OS_CHROMEOS)
  int oom_score = 0;
#endif
  int64_t tab_contents_id = 0;  // Unique ID per WebContents.
  bool is_auto_discardable = true;
};

typedef std::vector<TabStats> TabStatsList;

}  // namespace resource_coordinator

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

GCC 4.9.2 **sí** soporta esas características de C++11. Lo que sucede es que, por defecto, el estándar en cuestión no está habilitado. En vez de C++11 el compilador trata el código bajo el estándar C++03, que no soporta estas características.

Para habilitarlas compila con el flag `-std=c++11` (respeta las minúsculas)

Comment: esta flag ya la puse en mi compilacion y siguio tronando. Este bug esta reportado por los desarrolladores de chromium y su recomendacion es q se implemente manualmente el constructor, pero trate un par d ocasiones y no me funciono. No se si tu podrias mostrarme como quedaria implementado el constructor. La liga del bug es la siguiente: (este problema tambien sucede el algunas otras distros de linux como slax): https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=706963